# How can I dynamically set a CSS class list of an element in Angular from the class component?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

I want to set a property as a string and add that dynamically into a certain DOM element as a class list value.

```
<div [className]="propertyVariable"></div>
```

And inside the class component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css'],
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  propertyVariable: string;

  constructor() {}

  changePropertyVariable() {
    this.propertyVariable = 'class1 class2';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

So far it does not add the class list am setting to that variable. How do I properly bind to that property?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like `[class.className]="condition"` to add **className** if **condition** is true. In this scenario **className** is hardcoded in template.

If you want your class name to be dynamic you can use this syntax: `class="class1 class2 {{className}}"`.

For appending a list of classes you can use it like above only pass `className = classList.join(' ');` as the `className`.

So your template will be like: `class="class1 class2 itemOneFromList itemTwoFromList ..."`

I provided a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkrou1)

Comment: Hey @skyBlue, I don't know if you get me well but I want to be able to change the propertyVariable in that component and use it to store classes I wish to add into the class attribute.

Comment: Well 4 paragraphs I wrote. 2-3-4 will answer your needs.

Comment: Create a getter which acts like I said in paragraph 3. Then bind the result in template like paragraph 2.

Comment: I added stackblitz. @KlemLloydMwenya

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Angular ngClass directive with property binding to add classes dynamically?

```
<div [ngClass]="propertyVariable"></div>
```

https://angular.io/guide/property-binding

Comment: Should I read this as a rhetorical question?

Comment: @LeroyMeijer Yes if the proposal is a valid way to do it, else no. :-)